# d3.js chart with a dynamic and overlapping Y axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dynamic, charts, libraries

How can I show multiple time series overlapping each other with a dynamic `Y axis` that changes depending on which series is selected by the user.

The goal is to be able to compare patterns in the data, but it requires us to able able to display these charts overlapping on the `Y axis`.

```
Say TS1 (timeseries 1) has a dynamic range of [0 -> 2000] on the Y axis.
Say TS2 (timeseries 2) has a dynamic range of [500 -> 10,000] on the Y axis.

d3.js needs to be able to display both series on the graph overlapping (not stacking) on the Y axis.
```

Here is an example with pictures (Notice the change in Y Axis):

**Green Series Selected**:

[image: Chart with Green Series Selected]

**Blue Series Selected**:
[image: Chart with Blue Series Selected]

Comment: https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/e34791a32a54e015f57d

Comment: @RobinMackenzie unfortunately I am going to have 40+ series on the chart and this approach is not what I am looking for since we wont have the screen real-estate for that many axis.